# Change image padding based on position on screen - Android

Tags: android

I have a modification of a GridLayout and I want the children to have padding between each other but I want the ones on the edge of the screen to have no padding between them and the edge of the screen.
This means that some will have a right pad and no left while others my have a left pad and no right pad.

Is there a way to check if an image (or any view) is reaching the left/right border of the app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use paddingLeft and paddingRight so that you can control the padding of each element in the GridLayout